# Laravel Homestead php not loading extensions (sqlsrv) but already installed

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, homestead

I already added the extension sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv as well as mssql-tools, but when I load the page the error "driver not found (sqlsrv)" shows up. Also if I print phpinfo() trough the page the extension is not appearing.

But when I write php -m both extensions are listed, also if I run "php artisan tinker" and run the request to the MSSQL database is returns me data!

I don't know why that is happening, I already checked and php through terminal and phpinfo show I am using php 7.3.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: did you reload `php-fpm` ?

Comment: Yes I did, every time I performed a change I reloaded fpm and nginx

Comment: php ran from terminal (CLI) and phpfpm don't use the same config. You can't run a test from command line and expect the web does the same. Another issue is that nginx proxies php request to a unix socket. Are you proxying to php7.3-fpm or not? There's no need to reload nginx after enabling or disabling php extensions, all you need to reload is php-fpm. Make sure you're editing the correct config for the php version being used by your system.

Comment: When I run phpinfo() from web I edit the .ini marked as the primary and inserted the extensions manually and only one of the extensions appears, I don't know why the second (pdo_sqlsrv) is not showing up.

Comment: Did you include `pdo_sqlsrv` **after** `sqlsrv`? The order is important as the PDO library builds on the other one.

Comment: I just changed the order as you mentioned but I am unable to see the pdo_sqlsrv driver listed in the phpinfo(), I only see the sqlsrv driver and still not working